# How to append a HTML block to the existing HTML block within same <form> tag?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-append

I've following HTML block:

```
<form action="add_rebate_by_quat_volume.php" role="form" method="post">
              <div class="row">
                <input type="hidden" class="form-control" name="op" id="op" value="preview">
                <input type="hidden" class="form-control" name="id" id="id" value="">
                <input type="hidden" class="form-control" name="form_submitted" id="form_submitted" value="yes">
                <div class="col-xs-2">
                </div>

                <div style="float: clear;"></div>
                <div style="margin-left: 12px" class="col-xs-4">
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="company_name" class="col-lg-4">Manufacturer<span style="color:#FF0000">*</span></label>
                    <div class="col-lg-7">
                      <select id="company_id" name="company_id" class="form-control" onchange="GetAllProductByManufacturerID(this.value)">
                        <option value=""  selected='selected'>Select Manufacturer</option>

                          <option value="33" >Eywa Solutions</option>

                          <option value="37" >Amazon</option>

                          <option value="40" >Test</option>

                          <option value="42" >RK</option>

                          <option value="46" >Santa Margherita</option>
                                              </select>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div style="margin-left: -61px" class="col-xs-4">
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-lg-7">                      
                      <button style="float:right" class="btnAdd" type="button" class="btn btn-default" onclick="add_rebate(); return false;"><i class="icon-plus"></i> &nbsp;Add New Rebate</button>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              </br> 
              <div class="col-lg-2"></div>                  
              <div class="col-md-8">   
                <div style="overflow:auto" class="well">                 
                  </br>
                  <div class="table-responsive">
                    <table   id="blacklistgrid"  class="table table-bordered table-hover table-striped">
                      <thead>
                        <tr  id="Row1">
                          <th style="vertical-align:middle">Products</th>
                          <th style="vertical-align:middle">Pack Of</th>
                          <th style="vertical-align:middle">Quantity</th>
                          <th style="vertical-align:middle">Volume</th>
                          <th style="vertical-align:middle">Unit</th>
                          <th style="vertical-align:middle">Rebate Amount</th>
                        </tr>
                      </thead>
                      <tbody class="apnd-test">
                                                <tr id="reb1">
                          <td>
                            <div class="btn-group">
                              <select name="product_id" class="form-control prod_list">
                                <option value=""  selected='selected'>Select Product</option>
                                                              </select>
                            </div>
                          </td>
                          <td><input type="text" name="pack" id="pack" value="" class="form-control" size="8"/></td>
                          <td><input type="text" name="quantity" id="quantity" value="" class="form-control" size="8"/></td>
                          <td><input type="text" name="volume" id="volume" value="" class="form-control" size="8"/></td>
                          <td>
                            <div class="btn-group">
                              <select id="units" name="units" class="form-control">
                                <option value=""  selected='selected'>Select Unit</option>

                                <option value="5" >Microsecond</option>

                                <option value="7" >oz</option>

                                <option value="9" >ml</option>

                                <option value="10" >L</option>

                                <option value="12" >gms</option>
                                                               </select>
                            </div>
                          </td>
                          <td><input type="text" name="amount" id="amount" value="" class="form-control" size="9"/></td>
                        </tr>
                      </tbody>
                      <tfoot>
                        <tr id="reb2">
                          <td><button style="float:right; margin-bottom: 20px" class="btnAdd" type="button" class="btn btn-default" onclick="">&nbsp;Add</button></td>
                          <td></td>
                          <td></td>
                          <td></td>
                          <td></td>
                          <td></td>
                        </tr>
                      </tfoot>

                    </table>                  
                  </div>
                </div> <!-- /span8 -->              
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-xs-6">
                    <label for="name" class="col-lg-5">Rebate Start Date<span style="color:#FF0000">*</span></label>
                    <div class="col-lg-6">
                      <input class="form-control" placeholder="yyyy-mm-dd" type="date" name="rebate_start_date" value="">
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-xs-6">
                    <label for="name" class="col-lg-6">Rebate Expiry Date<span style="color:#FF0000">*</span></label>
                    <div class="col-lg-6">
                      <input class="form-control" placeholder="yyyy-mm-dd" type="date" name="rebate_expiry_date" value="">
                    </div>
                  </div> 
                </div>
                </br>
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-xs-6">
                    <label for="name" class="col-lg-5">Applicable States</label>
                    <div class="col-lg-7">
                      <select id="example28" multiple="multiple" name="applicable_states[]">
                                                                          <option value="1">Alabama</option>
                                                  <option value="2">Alaska</option>
                                                  <option value="3">Arizona</option>
                                                  <option value="4">Arkansas</option>
                                                  <option value="5">California</option>
                                                  <option value="6">Colorado</option>
                                                  <option value="7">Connecticut</option>
                                                  <option value="8">Delaware</option>
                                                  <option value="9">Florida</option>
                                                  <option value="10">Georgia</option>

                      </select>                          
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-xs-6">
                    <label for="name" class="col-lg-6">Rebate Total Count</label>
                    <div class="col-lg-6">
                      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="rebate_total_count" id="rebate_total_count" value="">
                    </div>
                  </div> 
                </div>
                </br>
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-xs-6">                    
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-xs-6">
                    <label for="name" class="col-lg-6"></label>
                    <div class="col-lg-6">
                      <button style="float:right" class="btnAdd" type="button" class="btn btn-default" onclick="add_rebate(); return false;"><i class="icon-plus"></i> &nbsp;Add New Rebate</button>
                    </div>
                  </div> 
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                  <div  class="col-xs-5"></div>
                  <div style="margin-left: -9px"  class="col-xs-5">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Preview</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Go Back</button>                        
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </form>
```

Now after clicking on any of the "Add New Rebate" button the following block should get append to the first block:

```
<div style="float: clear;"></div>
                <div style="margin-left: 12px" class="col-xs-4">
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="company_name" class="col-lg-4">Manufacturer<span style="color:#FF0000">*</span></label>
                    <div class="col-lg-7">
                      <select id="company_id" name="company_id" class="form-control" onchange="GetAllProductByManufacturerID(this.value)">
                        <option value=""  selected='selected'>Select Manufacturer</option>

                          <option value="33" >Eywa Solutions</option>

                          <option value="37" >Amazon</option>

                          <option value="40" >Test</option>

                          <option value="42" >RK</option>

                          <option value="46" >Santa Margherita</option>
                                              </select>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div style="margin-left: -61px" class="col-xs-4">
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-lg-7">                      
                      <button style="float:right" class="btnAdd" type="button" class="btn btn-default" onclick="add_rebate(); return false;"><i class="icon-plus"></i> &nbsp;Add New Rebate</button>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              </br> 
              <div class="col-lg-2"></div>                  
              <div class="col-md-8">   
                <div style="overflow:auto" class="well">                 
                  </br>
                  <div class="table-responsive">
                    <table   id="blacklistgrid"  class="table table-bordered table-hover table-striped">
                      <thead>
                        <tr  id="Row1">
                          <th style="vertical-align:middle">Products</th>
                          <th style="vertical-align:middle">Pack Of</th>
                          <th style="vertical-align:middle">Quantity</th>
                          <th style="vertical-align:middle">Volume</th>
                          <th style="vertical-align:middle">Unit</th>
                          <th style="vertical-align:middle">Rebate Amount</th>
                        </tr>
                      </thead>
                      <tbody class="apnd-test">
                                                <tr id="reb1">
                          <td>
                            <div class="btn-group">
                              <select name="product_id" class="form-control prod_list">
                                <option value=""  selected='selected'>Select Product</option>
                                                              </select>
                            </div>
                          </td>
                          <td><input type="text" name="pack" id="pack" value="" class="form-control" size="8"/></td>
                          <td><input type="text" name="quantity" id="quantity" value="" class="form-control" size="8"/></td>
                          <td><input type="text" name="volume" id="volume" value="" class="form-control" size="8"/></td>
                          <td>
                            <div class="btn-group">
                              <select id="units" name="units" class="form-control">
                                <option value=""  selected='selected'>Select Unit</option>

                                <option value="5" >Microsecond</option>

                                <option value="7" >oz</option>

                                <option value="9" >ml</option>

                                <option value="10" >L</option>

                                <option value="12" >gms</option>
                                                               </select>
                            </div>
                          </td>
                          <td><input type="text" name="amount" id="amount" value="" class="form-control" size="9"/></td>
                        </tr>
                      </tbody>
                      <tfoot>
                        <tr id="reb2">
                          <td><button style="float:right; margin-bottom: 20px" class="btnAdd" type="button" class="btn btn-default" onclick="">&nbsp;Add</button></td>
                          <td></td>
                          <td></td>
                          <td></td>
                          <td></td>
                          <td></td>
                        </tr>
                      </tfoot>

                    </table>                  
                  </div>
                </div> <!-- /span8 -->              
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-xs-6">
                    <label for="name" class="col-lg-5">Rebate Start Date<span style="color:#FF0000">*</span></label>
                    <div class="col-lg-6">
                      <input class="form-control" placeholder="yyyy-mm-dd" type="date" name="rebate_start_date" value="">
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-xs-6">
                    <label for="name" class="col-lg-6">Rebate Expiry Date<span style="color:#FF0000">*</span></label>
                    <div class="col-lg-6">
                      <input class="form-control" placeholder="yyyy-mm-dd" type="date" name="rebate_expiry_date" value="">
                    </div>
                  </div> 
                </div>
                </br>
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-xs-6">
                    <label for="name" class="col-lg-5">Applicable States</label>
                    <div class="col-lg-7">
                      <select id="example28" multiple="multiple" name="applicable_states[]">
                                                                          <option value="1">Alabama</option>
                                                  <option value="2">Alaska</option>
                                                  <option value="3">Arizona</option>
                                                  <option value="4">Arkansas</option>
                                                  <option value="5">California</option>
                                                  <option value="6">Colorado</option>
                                                  <option value="7">Connecticut</option>
                                                  <option value="8">Delaware</option>
                                                  <option value="9">Florida</option>
                                                  <option value="10">Georgia</option>


                      </select>                          
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-xs-6">
                    <label for="name" class="col-lg-6">Rebate Total Count</label>
                    <div class="col-lg-6">
                      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="rebate_total_count" id="rebate_total_count" value="">
                    </div>
                  </div> 
                </div>
                </br>
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-xs-6">                    
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-xs-6">
                    <label for="name" class="col-lg-6"></label>
                    <div class="col-lg-6">
                      <button style="float:right" class="btnAdd" type="button" class="btn btn-default" onclick="add_rebate(); return false;"><i class="icon-plus"></i> &nbsp;Add New Rebate</button>
                    </div>
                  </div> 
                </div>
```

How to achieve this using jQuery. Also there should be delete button on each newly added block for deleting the block if user wishes to. Following is the jsFiddle link for my original HTML block.

[**Jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/TrQz4/)

Comment: Please at least attempt to solve the problem before you ask for help

Comment: @arjan:I've added the jsFiddle link.

Answer (score 0):

its very simple

you can use the Appendto method

Give Class to Each of your div and use

```
  $( ".classA" ).appendTo( ".classB" );
```

and for deleting the Html again , you can use

```
   $(".classB").remove()
```

In Case you want to Copy the Element then

```
   $( ".classA" ).clone().appendTo( ".classB" );
```

Refrence: https://api.jquery.com/appendTo/

Answer (score 0):

Create a clonable tag. One that has all the stuff in it blank. Then clone and append.

```
<div id="clonethis" style="float: clear;"></div>
            <div style="margin-left: 12px" class="col-xs-4">
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="company_name" class="col-lg-4">Manufacturer<span style="color:#FF0000">*</span></label>
                <div class="col-lg-7">
                  <select id="company_id" name="company_id" class="form-control" onchange="GetAllProductByManufacturerID(this.value)">
                    <option value=""  selected='selected'>Select Manufacturer</option>

                      <option value="33" >Eywa Solutions</option>

                      <option value="37" >Amazon</option>

                      <option value="40" >Test</option>

                      <option value="42" >RK</option>

                      <option value="46" >Santa Margherita</option>
                                          </select>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div style="margin-left: -61px" class="col-xs-4">
              <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-lg-7">                      
                  <button style="float:right" class="btnAdd" type="button" class="btn btn-default" onclick="add_rebate(); return false;"><i class="icon-plus"></i> &nbsp;Add New Rebate</button>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          </br> 
          <div class="col-lg-2"></div>                  
          <div class="col-md-8">   
            <div style="overflow:auto" class="well">                 
              </br>
              <div class="table-responsive">
                <table   id="blacklistgrid"  class="table table-bordered table-hover table-striped">
                  <thead>
                    <tr  id="Row1">
                      <th style="vertical-align:middle">Products</th>
                      <th style="vertical-align:middle">Pack Of</th>
                      <th style="vertical-align:middle">Quantity</th>
                      <th style="vertical-align:middle">Volume</th>
                      <th style="vertical-align:middle">Unit</th>
                      <th style="vertical-align:middle">Rebate Amount</th>
                    </tr>
                  </thead>
                  <tbody class="apnd-test">
                                            <tr id="reb1">
                      <td>
                        <div class="btn-group">
                          <select name="product_id" class="form-control prod_list">
                            <option value=""  selected='selected'>Select Product</option>
                                                          </select>
                        </div>
                      </td>
                      <td><input type="text" name="pack" id="pack" value="" class="form-control" size="8"/></td>
                      <td><input type="text" name="quantity" id="quantity" value="" class="form-control" size="8"/></td>
                      <td><input type="text" name="volume" id="volume" value="" class="form-control" size="8"/></td>
                      <td>
                        <div class="btn-group">
                          <select id="units" name="units" class="form-control">
                            <option value=""  selected='selected'>Select Unit</option>

                            <option value="5" >Microsecond</option>

                            <option value="7" >oz</option>

                            <option value="9" >ml</option>

                            <option value="10" >L</option>

                            <option value="12" >gms</option>
                                                           </select>
                        </div>
                      </td>
                      <td><input type="text" name="amount" id="amount" value="" class="form-control" size="9"/></td>
                    </tr>
                  </tbody>
                  <tfoot>
                    <tr id="reb2">
                      <td><button style="float:right; margin-bottom: 20px" class="btnAdd" type="button" class="btn btn-default" onclick="">&nbsp;Add</button></td>
                      <td></td>
                      <td></td>
                      <td></td>
                      <td></td>
                      <td></td>
                    </tr>
                  </tfoot>

                </table>                  
              </div>
            </div> <!-- /span8 -->              
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-xs-6">
                <label for="name" class="col-lg-5">Rebate Start Date<span style="color:#FF0000">*</span></label>
                <div class="col-lg-6">
                  <input class="form-control" placeholder="yyyy-mm-dd" type="date" name="rebate_start_date" value="">
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-xs-6">
                <label for="name" class="col-lg-6">Rebate Expiry Date<span style="color:#FF0000">*</span></label>
                <div class="col-lg-6">
                  <input class="form-control" placeholder="yyyy-mm-dd" type="date" name="rebate_expiry_date" value="">
                </div>
              </div> 
            </div>
            </br>
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-xs-6">
                <label for="name" class="col-lg-5">Applicable States</label>
                <div class="col-lg-7">
                  <select id="example28" multiple="multiple" name="applicable_states[]">
                                                                      <option value="1">Alabama</option>
                                              <option value="2">Alaska</option>
                                              <option value="3">Arizona</option>
                                              <option value="4">Arkansas</option>
                                              <option value="5">California</option>
                                              <option value="6">Colorado</option>
                                              <option value="7">Connecticut</option>
                                              <option value="8">Delaware</option>
                                              <option value="9">Florida</option>
                                              <option value="10">Georgia</option>


                  </select>                          
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-xs-6">
                <label for="name" class="col-lg-6">Rebate Total Count</label>
                <div class="col-lg-6">
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="rebate_total_count" id="rebate_total_count" value="">
                </div>
              </div> 
            </div>
            </br>
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-xs-6">                    
              </div>
              <div class="col-xs-6">
                <label for="name" class="col-lg-6"></label>
                <div class="col-lg-6">
                  <button style="float:right" class="btnAdd" type="button" class="btn btn-default" onclick="add_rebate(); return false;"><i class="icon-plus"></i> &nbsp;Add New Rebate</button>
                </div>
              </div> 
            </div>
```

And then:

```
$('#clonethis').clone(true).removeAttr('id').appendTo('form');
```

Comment: Can you please modify your answer so that it could fit my needs perfectly?

Comment: There is only one issue - you're cloning id's as well. You need to account for these so that they are not duplicated in the document.

Comment: Then OP should notice not to include IDs in the inner stuff, only classes.

Answer (score 0):

You will want to group your fields in an element with a class name like 'copyMe'. Bind your click event like so:

```
$('#addRebate').on('click', function (){
    $('.copyMe:eq(0)').clone().appendTo('form');
});
```

If the remove button is inside the cloned group (with a class of 'removeCopy'), then binding to it is easy as well:

```
$(document).on('click','.removeCopy', function (){
    $(this).closest('.copyMe').remove();
});
```

If there are any ids or names in the cloned group, it might be good to increment them or otherwise change them somehow.

Answer (score 0):

It's kind of overkill to call Jquery for something as simple a task as this, native Javascript should work just fine to write the second block. Keep in mind you can still use native JS functions after calling Jquery. The easy way out would be to simply use plain Javascript's innerHTML with a += sign to append it to the current code.

```
<div id="wrapper">
put first block here...
</div>
<script LANGUAGE="Javascript">
// put the id of the element to add the second block to and what to add to it below
document.getElementById("wrapper").innerHTML += "second block without any newlines here";
</script>
```

But innerHTML is not an official part of the spec and could be removed from browsers at any time.
Another easier option could be to make a div with the second block but just make it invisible at first via CSS:

```
<div id="secondblock" style="display:none;">
...
</div>
<script LANGUAGE="Javascript">
document.getElementById("secondblock").style.display="inline";
</script>
```

However, the official way to do it is to use appendChild/insertBefore. This is a convoluted method but if you really must do it according to the spec, here is a link to explain them. http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/dom2.shtml